# How to set scrollWheelZoom to false in a map using leaflet in Shiny?

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I am using Shiny to build an application using the leaflet library.

I create the map at the ui.R using leafletOutput() and render it at server.R using renderLeaflet(). I can add markers, set zooming factor, etc. Everything works like a charm.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to set scrollWheelZoom to false. I really need this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Currently this is not possible in the R package **leaflet**, but you can file a feature request: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to hack the generated HTML to insert a JavaScript call to enable it?

Comment: Sorry, I do not see an obvious hack, either. My colleagues may have an idea if you file a feature request. A really back hack could happen here, though: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/b63d7c045cb1d7191365692bc128653a20a45144/inst/htmlwidgets/leaflet.js#L652-L657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Yihui on the comment above, there is no way to do it.
I filled an issue at leaflet to ask this feature: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/84

Tks